# Remove first parameter character with GhostDoc

Tags: ghostdoc

I have paramters named like pOtherColor.
Using ghostdoc I get "The p Other Color".
The Macro is $(Name.Words.TheAndAllAsSentence)

There is a macro ExceptFirst - but this gives "Other Color".
What I would need is a macro like "TheAndExceptFirstAsSentence"

I tried to "chain" macros - but I couldn't get it working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you you using the free version of GhostDoc. The screenshot below illustrates the rule configuration that you are looking for in GhostDoc Free.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: This works "partial" - 
  /// <param name="pOurFirstElement">The our first element</param>
  /// <param name="OurFirstElement">Our first element.</param>
  /// <param name="pAnImportantReasonForShuttingDown">The an important reason for shutting down</param>
  /// <param name="AnImportantReasonForShuttingDown">An important reason for shutting down.</param>
  public ShutdownRequestEventArgs(string pOurFirstElement, string OurFirstElement,
   string pAnImportantReasonForShuttingDown, string AnImportantReasonForShuttingDown) {

Comment: @ManniAT sorry, the snippet you provided is hard to read. Could you please give me examples of what you are trying to achieve and and what you are getting. Not quite clear at this point what you mean it works partial... Thanks!

Comment: Hi,
simply try to document the following method

ShutdownRequestEventArgs(string pOurFirstElement, string OurFirstElement, string pAnImportantReasonForShuttingDown, string AnImportantReasonForShuttingDown)